# JavaFX Memory Leak

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, javafx-8

I had written a software by using javaFx but I noticed memory leak in JVM 
so after 5 minutes it will stop with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

I search alot but I did not find solution.
I will share code about openinig new page in same stage and scene

```
DashboardController.centerStatic.getChildren().clear();
FXMLLoader fl =new FXMLLoader("page.fxml",Lang.getResourceBundle());

//static centerStatic    
DashboardController.centerStatic.getChildren().setAll((AnchorPane)fl.load());
```

when I call the new page it will execute queries and adding listeners and eventhandlers so it will fill memory with 50 mb 
but after call new page it is not free the memory
so I get memory leak after 5 minutes

please help us 
thanks

Comment: yes I  mean OutOfMemoryError  , and I close all opened resources

Comment: The listeners are probably stopping GC.  You may want to read about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/WeakChangeListener.html

Comment: Thank you for your replay , I change all listeners to weaklisteners but it still get big memroy and make memory leak ?

Comment: It's very hard to diagnose, even if you showed all the code.  I suggest https://visualvm.java.net/ .  It's already in your jdk and your ide probably has a way to use it as well.